# Motion of gears

Tags: mechanical-engineering, dynamics

Gear A and B will have the same speed and tangential component of acceleration at the point where they mesh.why? From plane motion of rigid bodies energy and momentum methods.

Comment: Because otherwise they wouldnt mesh for very long.

Comment: If they don't then one will loose teeth... permanently...

Comment: Hi, we don't generally do people's homework here.  But if you'd like some hints, please post a diagram of the gears in question and any analysis you may have attempted.

Answer (score 1):

when the two gears mesh with each other,there is a point contact in between the two gears.
Since a single point in 3D space can not have different velocity or acceleration at a given point in time,thus both the gears have same tangential acceleration.

Comment: Yes, it may be better to explain that there are 2 points one in each object. For them to be in contact over time they must occupy same space so they must move as one.  (though this only really applies to rolling)